# How to send multiple rendering from a controller in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, middleware, silex

In order to **fix users waiting pain** due to some (already optimized) **DB calculations : about 3 to 10 seconds**.

We need to make a **waiting page during the long calculation process** as every flights comparators do for example.

Our architecture is based on **Silex 1.3**.

What we want to achieve is:

1. Trigger controller action by routing URL matching and start calculations
2. Make a first render without modifying the request : twig waiting page
3. At the end of calculations render the final twig with all data
   driven by calculations

I tested it with `$app->before` attribute bound to the route and returning/rendering stops the calculation...

So how to do that double rendering based on calculation?

**NOT SUITABLE SOLUTION FOR OUR PURPOSE:**

The first workaround I implemented is a JavaScript show/hide spinner element.
But this is not a suitable solution because we really need to get a temporary rendering from server.

**EDIT**

The first render is working but I'm not enable to do the second rendering by calling my controller action (defined as controller as service) which is doing the rendering and I get this **EXCEPTION**:

> RuntimeException: Accessed request service outside of request scope. Try moving that call to a before handler or controller.

Here is my **controller definition**:

```
 $app['index.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new IndexController($app);
});
```

Here is my **route definition**:

```
$app->get('/vue-ensemble/{city}', function (Request $request, Application $app)
{
    $content = function() use ($app) {
        $wait = $app->render('index_test.twig', array());
        $wait->send();
        flush();

        // Long process
        $process = $app['index.controller']->overviewAction();
        $process->send();
        flush();
    };

    return $app->stream($content);
});
```

Here is my **controller action**:

```
  protected $app;
    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function overviewAction(){
          /* DO LONG PROCESS */
           return $this->app->render('overview.twig', array('some elements'=>'some values'));
        }
```

**EDIT '**

Unfortunately I still have the same issue, here is the stack trace:

```
    fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Accessed request service outside of request scope. Try moving that call to a before handler or controller.' in C:\inforisq\application\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Application.php on line 150
( ! ) RuntimeException: Accessed request service outside of request scope. Try moving that call to a before handler or controller. in C:\inforisq\application\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Application.php on line 150
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  240848  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.5250  4506656 Silex\Application->run( )   ...\index.php:14
3   0.7040  13098664    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->send( )  ...\Application.php:564
4   0.7040  13101248    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse->sendContent( )   ...\Response.php:372
5   0.7040  13101296    call_user_func:{C:\inforisq\application\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\StreamedResponse.php:90} ( ) ...\StreamedResponse.php:90
6   0.7040  13101384    {closure:C:\inforisq\application\app\config\routing.php:20-27}( )   ...\StreamedResponse.php:90
7   0.7040  13118168    Inforisq\Controller\IndexController->overviewAction( )  ...\routing.php:25
8   0.7040  13118328    Lib\InforisqApplication->place_analyzeURL( )    ...\IndexController.php:64
9   0.7060  13306184    Indicator\Repository\PlaceRepository->analyzeURLPlace( )    ...\PlaceTrait.php:23
10  0.7060  13306304    Lib\InforisqApplication->request( ) ...\PlaceRepository.php:423
11  0.7060  13306384    Pimple->offsetGet( )    ...\PlaceRepository.php:26
12  0.7060  13306464    Silex\Application->Silex\{closure}( )   ...\Pimple.php:83
```

Comment: Could you please add some traces for your exception ? From where is it thrown ?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: What is this call `11  0.7060  13306384    Pimple->offsetGet( )    ...\PlaceRepository.php:26` ?

Comment: It's a class having a simple construct with $app injected : __construct(Application $app)

Comment: It's clearly the issue

Comment: Thanks we are working on injection improvement!

Comment: Updated my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse`

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#streaming-a-response

### Edit

When you return a response from a controller, the kernel calls `$response->send()`, but internally `Response::send()` calls `Response::sendHeaders()` then `Response::sendContent()`.

So `sendHeaders()` in this case will be send once by the kernel on the streamed response, then if you need other `Response` objects in your callback for convenience, you must call only `sendContent()`.

If you need to custom the http response code or the headers you can pass them as arguments in the method `Application::stream($callback, $statusCode, array $headers)`.

Before editing my answer I used `flush()` like the example in the symfony docs, but you may need some cache to be able to handle a second controller in the callback so first use `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` for the "waiting" response.

```
use \Silex\Application;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app->get('/vue-ensemble/{city}', function (Request $request, Application $app, $city)
{
    /** @var \Acme\Controller\IndexController $indexController */
    $indexController = $app['index.controller'];

    /** @var Response $wait */
    $wait = $app->render('wait.html.twig', array('city' => $city);

    // Callback
    $content = function () use ($wait, $indexController) {
        ob_start();
        $wait->sendContent();
        ob_flush();

        $indexController->overviewAction($city)->sendContent();
        flush();
    }

    return $app->stream($content);

    // Will send a \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse
    // equivalent to :

    // $streamedResponse = new StreamedResponse();
    // $streamedResponse->setCallback($content);
    //
    // return streamedResponse;
});
```

## Edit 2:

You should only pass the services you need in a constructor of service instead of pass the whole container each time :

```
$app['index.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new IndexController($app['twig'], $app['some_helper']);
});

$app['some_helper'] = $app->protect(function($arg1, arg2) use ($app) {
    $helper = new \Acme\Helper($app['some_dependency'];

    return $helper->help(arg1, arg2);
});
```

Then :

```
class IndexController
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Engine $twig, \Acme\Helper $helper)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function overview($city)
    {
        $some_arg = ...

        $viewArg = $this->helper($some_arg, $city);

        return $this->twig->renderResponse('overview.twig', array('some elements' => $viewArg));
    }
}
```

But then it would be better if the `indexController` just returned `$this->twig->render(...)` but then it should be `echo $indexController->overview($city)`

Comment: Is this is ok for custom Traits injection ? In our bootstrap file we are instantiating : $app = new InforisqApplication(array('debug' => true));

Comment: ...and InforisqApplication class extends Application and is making all the use (one per Trait)

Comment: a Trait is not a service of the container, so you would need to pass all the container (the app) to use their methods

Comment: a Trait should not be use in a service, only in a controller

Comment: Strange behavior, Services should intercept all the Business part of the code (of any applications) and Traits are only a Method Helper to easy the code factoring. Saying this, Traits are fundamentally used by Services...

Comment: What you say is true fundamentally, bit it is not compatible with the architecture of Silex. Using `$app->render()` is equivalent to `$app['twig']->renderResponse()` and controllers receive by default the $app in Silex. But if you want tu use that trait in a service it means you have to pass it the whole `$app` instead of `$app['twig']`

Comment: It is actually working with finest injection but the double rendering result is a combined render (page 1 + page 2 displayed). May we should use a redirect for the second page ?

Comment: Seems complicated to redirect on a preloaded page without reloading it, you would need to use a custom cache process. what about using an iframe with a `onload` js function ?

Comment: You should better use an ajax call on the second controller

Comment: Have you heard about ReactJS, it can work pretty well with framework like Silex or Symfony, but it needs a fine configuration first

Comment: Javascript already done, and we found a solution to make the redirect. ReactJS is not useful for us there. Thx